# Implementing a OAuth2 server with Spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I need to implement an Authorization server using Spring.

I'm using this tutorial: http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

But the author put both the needed resource and the server in same application.

What I need is an Auth server to hold users, autenticate and give tokens and the resources must be in some other applications so a user can get a token and use it in all my applications.

How can I change the code above to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

in this tutorial you use a webservice to test the authentication, well simply instead of using "localhost" try the ip of the server from another connected to the network machine.
instead of GET http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/user/
Use  http://**Server_IP**:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/user/

Comment: Ok. I understood this part but the credential manager AND the client are both in same code. How can I split this in two applications so one can hold the security manager and the other will be the client with secured resources. And how the server will tell the client that the user "Foo" is logged in?